# Adding additional maven repositories for android build.gradle file is not working

Tags: java, android, maven, build, gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/mobile/Android/common/rest-api/1.0/"
        artifactUrls "http://mycompany.com/nexus/content/repositories/mobile"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'Android.myApp:rest-api:1.0'
}
```

above the build.gradle file. When I execute gradle tasks I'm getting

A problem occurred configuring root project 'app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve Android.myApp:rest-api:1.0.
>        Required by:
>            :app:unspecified
>   Target host must not be null, or set in parameters.

confirmed pom files and jar files are present in the maven repo.

Answer (score 0):

Its silly.

```
maven {
    url 'http:////mycompany.app.com/nexus/content/repositories/mobile'
}
```

url should contain 4 //// after http. We are using nexus and this fixes the issue.